# Why does Lego Indiana Jones 2 skip levels?

Tags: lego-indiana-jones-2

I have successfully played the Lego Indiana Jones 2: The Adventure Continues once, but now that I try to play it again it is starting to skip certain levels.

In the main menu, there are a couple of crates and each have different adventures you can go on. Well when I click to start the adventure I remember from the first time I played that there was a little skit that played. Well this time when I played the adventure, in the beginning it had a different skit as if I had already beat the first quarter of the game.

Why is that?

Comment: Could you explain what is happending a bit more? What levels are being skipped and what happens when they are skipped?

Comment: In the main menu, there are a couple of crates and each have different adventures you can go on. Well when I click to start the adventure I remember from the first time I played that there was a little skit that played. Well this time when I played the adventure, in the beginning it had a different skit as if I had already beat the first quarter of the game. Im sorry if this doesn't make any more sense but hopefully it does...